# How to click on a Popup Confirmation alert (Selenium Webdriver / Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a popup confirmation alert using Selenium Webdriver / Ruby, but even with the xpath I can't click on the OK or Cancel button.

(popup window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQHDH.jpg)

HTML code:

```
<div>
  <a onclick="$find('confirm1545915453689').close(true);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">OK</span></span></a>
  <a onclick="$find('confirm1545915453689').close(false);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">Cancel</span></span></a>
</div>
```

Code I tried:

```
browser.find_element(:xpath => '//*[@id="confirm1545919261219_content"]/div/div[2]/a[2]/span/span').click
```

and

```
browser.find_element(:xpath => '//td[.="Cancel"]').click
```

Thanks for ur time

Comment: Hi, If you are using Ruby Selenium then use WATIR which is a nice wrapper around selenium . While you ask question on WATIR, tag wait tag.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Watir is really good? I'll give it a try

Comment: Yes, that's a good wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding. Timing synchronization is awesome in watir, you don't have to write xpath in WATIR.

Comment: OMG, I'll try Watir asap hahahaahah, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have any errors while trying to click?

try following locator:

```
browser.find_element(:xpath, "//span[@class='rwInnerSpan' and text()='OK']").click;
browser.find_element(:xpath, "//span[@class='rwInnerSpan' and text()='Cancel']").click;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Infern0! Works perfectly.